# Typecast or decode C objects in Java

Tags: java, c

How can I typecast or decode a C object in Java without using intermediates like CORBA, SWIG etc.??

I need a direct method from C to Java.

Comment: This is not very clear, I'm afraid. You can't "typecast" between C and Java, they're different languages. What kind of access to the C object do you have? Is it a plain `struct`, or something more complicated? More details, please.

Comment: How does the object appear to the JVM? Is it in a byte array?

Comment: @unwind Its a plain `struct`, I know the process to convert it to xml through CORBA and read the data from it in java. But I need a direct mehod?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/), which allows you to have Java methods whose implementation is "native" (compiled non-Java code) and also allows you to embed a JVM in a "native" (compiled non-Java) application. The "native" part can be coded in C.

Comment: But I need to poll messages in java, so how does JNI supports polling? Is there any way I can directly exchange messages between C and Java?

Comment: @SrujanSimha: JNI **is** how you directly exchange messages between C and Java. *"...how does JNI supports polling?"* With JNI, you can make the implementation of a Java method actually be code you wrote in C and compiled. So just call that Java method (which calls the C code) on whatever interval is appropriate. Voila, polling.